# Flutter List View Data Duplication when I do setState and pagination with StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter

I am implementation the list data from API to show in list view. There I am using `Streambuiler` and pull to refresh [library](https://pub.dev/packages/pull_to_refresh)  for scrolling changes. I set the new data from API to local list inside `StreamBuilder`. Every time when I made `setState` for state changes. The `StreamBuilder` rebuild and setting data again. Then my list was duplicated, I do not know yet what's wrong with my code. I am developing the App with flutter recently. Please check my code what is wrong in there.

```
  class OrderListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OrderListScreenState createState() => _OrderListScreenState();
}

class _OrderListScreenState extends State<OrderListScreen> {

  String showingFromDate, showingToDate;
  OrderBloc _orderBloc;
  OrderListOb _orderListOb = OrderListOb();
  int paginationPage = 0;
  DateTime fromDate, toDate;
  List<Orders> _orderList = [];
  var _refreshController = RefreshController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _orderBloc = OrderBloc();
    initDate();
    fetchAPI();
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _orderBloc.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: defaultAppBar("Order List Screen", showBackArrow: false),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  textView("From Date", isBold: true),
                  textView("To Date", isBold: true),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  ActionChip(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                    avatar: Icon(
                      Icons.calendar_today_sharp,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 18,
                    ),
                    backgroundColor: PRIMARY_COLOR,
                    label: textView(showingFromDate, textColor: Colors.white),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _selectDate(context, isFromDate: true);
                    },
                  ),
                  ActionChip(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                    avatar: Icon(
                      Icons.calendar_today_sharp,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 18,
                    ),
                    backgroundColor: PRIMARY_COLOR,
                    label: textView(showingToDate, textColor: Colors.white),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _selectDate(context, isFromDate: false);
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              StreamBuilder(
                stream: _orderBloc.orderListStream(),
                initialData:
                    BaseResponse(data: null, message: MsgState.loading),
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  BaseResponse ob = snapshot.data;
                  if (ob.message == MsgState.loading) {
                    return Center(
                      child: Container(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      ),
                    );
                  } else if (ob.message == MsgState.data ) {
                    _orderListOb = OrderListOb();
                    _orderListOb = ob.data;
                    _orderList.addAll(_orderListOb.result.orders);
                    return buildListView();
                  } else {
                    return handleErrorWidget(ob.data);
                  }
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }


  Widget buildListView() {
    return Container(
      height: 450,
      child: SmartRefresher(
        enablePullUp: _orderListOb.result.orders.length > 9,
        enablePullDown: true,
        onRefresh: () {
          print("Pull To Refresh");
        },
        onLoading: () {
          paginationPage = _orderListOb.result.pagination.nextId;
          fetchAPI(); //Do pagination
        },
        controller: _refreshController,
        child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: _orderList.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    context.navigateName("order_detail", data: {
                      'isAcceptOrder': true,
                      'order_id': _orderList[index].id
                    });
                  },
                  child: orderItemWidget(_orderList[index],
                      isAcceptedOrder: false));
            }),
      ),
    );
  }


  void fetchAPI() {
    _orderBloc.getOrderList(
        serviceId: ServiceTypes.AIRCON_SERVICE.value,
        fromDate: DateUtil.requestDateFormat(fromDate.toString()),
        toDate: DateUtil.requestDateFormat(toDate.toString()),
        page: paginationPage);
  }

  void initDate() {
    showingFromDate = DateUtil.covertDate(DateUtil.getCurrentDate().toString());
    showingToDate = DateUtil.covertDate(DateUtil.getCurrentDate().toString());
    fromDate = DateUtil.getCurrentDate();
    toDate = DateUtil.getCurrentDate();
  }

  void resetData() {
    print("Clear");
    paginationPage = 0;
    _orderList.clear();
  }

 _selectDate(BuildContext context, {bool isFromDate = true}) async {
final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
  context: context,
  initialDate: isFromDate ? fromDate : toDate, // Refer step 1
  firstDate: DateTime(2000),
  lastDate: DateTime(2025),
);
if (picked != null)
  setState(() {
    if (isFromDate) {
      showingFromDate = DateUtil.covertDate(picked.toString());
      fromDate = picked;
    } else {
      showingToDate = DateUtil.covertDate(picked.toString());
      toDate = picked;
    }
    resetData();
    fetchAPI();
  });


 }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're doing `_orderList.addAll(_orderListOb.result.orders);` . Instead, you should clean the list before or just                     `_orderList=_orderListOb.result.orders;`

Answer (score 0):

Check for existence the value before adding to list, if list doesnt contain the value then add like this:

```
    if(!_orderList.contains(_orderListOb.result.orders))
        _orderList.addAll(_orderListOb.result.orders);
```

I hope it will work!